# A question about Mostow's theorem for self-adjoint groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

In Mostow's paper [Self-adjoint groups](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2007099?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), one can find the following property.

> **Theorem.** Let $G\subset \mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$ be a reductive real algebraic subgroup. Then there exists $a\in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $a G a^{-1}$ is self-adjoint.

Here the notion "self-adjoint" means this group is invariant relative to the matrix transpose.

Now I am interested in the following relevant question.

> **Question.** Find and describe all the reductive $\mathbb{Q}$-subgroups $G_{\mathbb{Q}}\subset \mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{Q}}$ such that there exists $a\in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ with $a G_{\mathbb{Q}} a^{-1}$ being self-adjoint.

Hints and suggestions are all welcomed! Thanks very much!

Comment: For $n=2$, the (connected) reductive subgroups can be described. For nonzero $u$ write $A_u=\begin{pmatrix}0 & u\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Let $T_u$ be the centralizer of $A_u$ in $GL_2$ and $T'_u=T_u\cap SL_2$. Then the connected reductive $Q$-subgroups are $Q$-conjugate to some $T_u$, $T'_u$, $\{1\}$, $SL_2$, or $GL_2$. Then the last 3 are self-adjoint and $T_u$, $T'_u$ are self-adjoint iff $u=\pm 1$, and hence each of $T_u$, $T'_u$ is $Q$-conjugate to a self-adjoint subgroup if and only if $u$ is a square or minus a square.

Comment: Conceptually, Mostow's result is really about making compatible Cartan involutions for an inclusion between connected reductive $\mathbf{R}$-groups (the Cartan involution on the possibly disconnected $G(\mathbf{R})$ for a connected reductive $\mathbf{R}$-group $G$ and choice of maximal compact subgroup of $G(\mathbf{R})$ is made in 24.6 of Borel's *Linear Algebraic Groups* (2nd ed.)).  That it can be expressed via transpose (equivalently "transpose-inverse", the actual Cartan involution of ${\rm{GL}}_n(\mathbf{R})$) is sort of an accident, so is the motivation idle curiosity or something more?

Comment: In complement to my previous comment, since $T_u$ is conjugate to $T_{s^2u}$ for every nonzero $s$ and idem for $T'_u$, we can restrict to those $u$ that are $\pm$ products of distinct primes. So, for such $u$, the only ones that are $Q$-conjugate to a self-adjoint group are for $u=\pm 1$.  Also I forgot a few $Q$-subtori, namely the split torus $T_1$ admits infinitely many 1-dimensional $Q$-subtori (not only $T'_1$). This is the only oversight: the only $Q$-subtori of $T_u$ for nonsquare $u$ are $T'_u$ (anisotropic) and the center of $GL_2$ (split).